# STM32F051 - Different idle state depending on overcurrent input

Tags: timer, stm32, pwm, stm32f0

I have a STM32F051 driving a H-bridge (with proper gate drivers and overcurrent pulse sent back to the MCU) which power a transformer, using TIM1 and complementary signals (and dead time generation).

I am trying to configure a different "safe" state depending on which overcurrent pulse I receive:

- On high side overcurrent, turn off low side fets, turn on high side fets.
- On low side overcurrent, turn off high side fets, turn on low side fets.

Idea is to improve overcurrent performance on an inverter.

Is there a possibility to manually set the outputs of the timers to a defined state immediately when receiving a pulse on a GPIO ? I tried with the break function, but you can only set one predefined "safe" state. For my application I need two (for now, more to come).

Comment: Is using the inverted timer output an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found the result and I share it with you.

The [source code](https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3/blob/19f1160ad1121af71c88c9fcd3e8f3c87db4cb58/include/libopencm3/stm32/common/timer_common_all.h) and [examples](https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3-examples/blob/fe6a2b5f13d1a938e6e1d5980b27682bd47407d2/examples/stm32/f1/stm32-h103/pwm_6step/pwm_6step.c) of libopencm3  helped me to find the answer.

```
#define TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_INACTIVE     (0x2 << 4)
#define TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_FORCE_LOW    (0x4 << 4)
#define TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_FORCE_HIGH   (0x5 << 4)
#define TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_PWM2         (0x7 << 4)

#define TIM_CCMR1_OC2M_INACTIVE     (0x2 << 12)
#define TIM_CCMR1_OC2M_FORCE_LOW    (0x4 << 12)
#define TIM_CCMR1_OC2M_FORCE_HIGH   (0x5 << 12)
#define TIM_CCMR1_OC2M_PWM2         (0x7 << 12)
```

Utility functions to disable and enable outputs.

```
void disable_pwm(){
    TIM1->CCER &= ~(TIM_CCER_CC1E | TIM_CCER_CC1NE | TIM_CCER_CC2E | TIM_CCER_CC2NE);
}

void enable_pwm(){
    TIM1->CCER |= (TIM_CCER_CC1E | TIM_CCER_CC1NE | TIM_CCER_CC2E | TIM_CCER_CC2NE);
}
```

Here is how to force the H bridge to short the load to ground as an example.

```
TIM1->CCMR1 &= ~TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_Msk;
TIM1->CCMR1 |= TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_FORCE_LOW;

TIM1->CCMR1 &= ~TIM_CCMR1_OC2M_Msk;
TIM1->CCMR1 |= TIM_CCMR1_OC2M_FORCE_LOW;
```

Hope this will be useful to someone else!